# How to read yahoo email with python

Tags: python

tried to use the following code to read yahoo email.
The error message says "NB: mailbox is locked by server from here to 'quit()'"

Q> How to fix the issue?

```
import poplib
from email import parser

pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.mail.yahoo.com')
pop_conn.user('xxxx@yahoo.com')
pop_conn.pass_('xxxx')

#Get messages from server:
iMessageCount = len(pop_conn.list()[1])
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, iMessageCount + 1)]


# Concat message pieces:
messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]

#Parse message intom an email object:
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
for message in messages:
    print message['subject']


13 #Get messages from server:


/usr/lib/python2.7/poplib.pyc in pass_(self, pswd)
    187         NB: mailbox is locked by server from here to 'quit()'
    188         """
--> 189         return self._shortcmd('PASS %s' % pswd)
```

Comment: is POP3 access free and enabled by default in Yahoo? I thought Yahoo Mail had a more restrictive approach than say GMail on that.

Comment: Any method will be fine. As long as I can read all emails from my yahoo account

Comment: Maybe you need to go through their API: http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/  I have a Yahoo account and POP3 access is only available if I upgrade to Yahoo Plus

Comment: Just to verify one thing, do you have your mailbox opened anywhere else (browser, 3:d party application etc)?